# Trocar Tabela por tópico

Tags: php

eu tenho os dados a serem mostrados assim atualmente.

```
echo "<table>"; 
echo  "<tr><td>Nome:</td>";
echo "<td>".$exibe["Nome"]."</td></tr>";

echo  "<tr><td>Morada:</td>"; echo "<td>";
if ($exibe['Morada']){ echo $exibe['Morada'];}else{echo 'N/D';} echo "</td></tr>";

echo "<tr><td>Tipo:</td>";echo"<td>";
if($exibe['Tipo']){ echo $exibe['Tipo'];}else{echo 'N/D';} echo "</td></tr>";

echo "<tr><td>Email:</td>"; echo "<td>";
if($exibe['Email']){ echo $exibe['Email'];}else{echo 'N/D';} echo "</td></tr>";
```

Atualmente os dados são mostrados todos na mesma pagina em forma de tabela ou seja:

```
 id - 1
 Nome[1] - Jorge
 Morada[1] - Rua do Sol
 Email[1] - jorge@jorge.pt

 id - 2
 Nome[2] - Pedro
 Morada[2] - Rua da agua
 Email[2] - pedro@pedro.pt
```

Eu quero alterar isso para cada id aparecer numa pasta ou janela diferente. Pois irei ter iumeros Id's e se deixo tudo na mesma pagina fica muito extenso

Mais claro?

Comment: Não entendi, esse Id seria `$exibe['Id']`?

Comment: Cada "Topico" guardaria a informação de cada ID que fosse inserido.
Topico1 = Id1
Topico2 = Id2
....

Comment: Não está dando para entender a pergunta. É sobre a estrutura do HTML? Sobre como pegar o Id no php? Você pode editar a pergunta para deixá-la mais clara?

Comment: Cada tabela seria um tópico?

Comment: Lembre-se de escolher a melhor resposta. Você faz diversas perguntas e quem responde gosta de ter um feedback também. Abraço.

Answer (score 2):

Não entendi, mas vou tentar.
Acho que ele ta querendo listar e associar os resultados ao ID. Vamos tentar.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
// função javascript que receberá id e redirecionará para página ver.php passando o id
function go(id) {
    window.location = 'ver.php?id=' + id;
}
<script>

<table>
<tr>
    <td>Id:</td>
    <td>Nome:</td>
    <td>Tipo:</td>
    <td>Morada:</td>
    <td>Email:</td>
</tr>

<?php
// Se você tiver um array com vários sub-arrays com a estrutura do seu $exibe
foreach ($resultados as $exibe)
{
    // Primeiro recebo as variaveis
    $id = $exibe["id"];
    $nome = $exibe["Nome"];

    // Uso do operador ternário para simplificar o if
    $morada = ($exibe['Morada']) ? $exibe['Morada'] : "N/D" ;
    $tipo = ($exibe['Tipo']) ? $exibe['Tipo'] : "N/D" ;
    $email = ($exibe['Email']) ? $exibe['Email'] : "N/D" ;

    // Quando clicar na linha ele vai jogar para a página correspondente
    // O css é só pra deixar com a mãozinha quando por o mouse em cima
    echo  "<tr onclick='go($id);' style='cursor: pointer;'>";
    echo  "<td>$id</td>";
    echo  "<td>$nome</td>";
    echo  "<td>$tipo</td>";
    echo  "<td>$morada</td>";
    echo  "<td>$email</td>";
    echo  "</tr>";
}
?>   
</table>
```

Veja mais sobre: [Operador Ternário](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary)